# 'A program file was not specified in the launch configuration' on Eclipse Luna CDT (C Project)

Tags: c, eclipse, configuration, compilation, eclipse-cdt

So I am new to CDT (even though I have worked with C and Eclipse Java before), and seem to be getting the error as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Now, when I check the `Run Configurations`, the application field of the debug applicaiton seems to be empty, as shown below:

[image]

Finally, when I check the actual physical location of where the debug executable should be, the folder seems to be empty, even though I am going through the build process.

[image]

Does anyone know why this problem is being caused, and why exactly eclipse isn't building/compiling my executable?

**NOTE** : I am currently using Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your program doesn't compile correctly, maybe because you have a build error at the compiler level... 
Try to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and see if in the problems section you get some errors of the compiler .

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with developing Java in Eclipse, then you might have hit a problem that the default setting for Java is to continuously build. However for CDT you need to tell Eclipse to build the project. This can be done by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to build all projects in the workspace, or right-clicking on the desired project and selecting `Build Project`.

Once you have the first build of your project, future builds can be completed automatically by using the `Build (if required) before launching` option in `Window | Preferences | Run/Debug | Launching` as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Once you do the first build and set up your launch configuration. Then the edit/debug cycle becomes very efficient, simply code and hit Run or Debug button when ready.

Comment: I have submitted a bug request for this less than perfect new user flow. You can follow it on Bugzilla if you desire https://bugs.eclipse.org/479586

Comment: Very helpful tip, but alex answered the right answer first and I must respect that. Either ways, I'll keep an eye out on that bug.